Am getting an error trying to install VS code on my Windows 10
I want to install VS Code application on my Windows 10 laptop and I am getting an error message


That doesn't seem like an installation problem, but rather a problem running the program executable.  How did you install VS Code? Did you download it from here? Your Windows version in 64-bit as well (likely is)

You're trying to install 64-bit VSCode on your 32-bit system. Last version supported for Windows 10 32-bit is 1.8.3:

The last stable VS Code version to support Windows 32-bit is 1.83
(September 2023)

You can download it officially from here
